# Integrating Jade in Yeoman's server/watch/reload tasks

Tags: node.js, build-automation, pug, gruntjs, yeoman

I've been playing around with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) & [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). I've created a small test app via `yeoman init angular` (it's an angular app, but that's not the point here)...

When I enter `yeoman server` at the command line, it will:

- compile [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) & [compass](http://compass-style.org/) files
- start a server
- start a browser
- watch & reload coffeescript & compass changes in the browser

Which is a great feature of Yeoman!

**Now I want the same feature with Jade.** So I installed **[grunt-jade](https://github.com/phated/grunt-jade)** via `npm install grunt-jade` and added the following config in **GruntFile.js** to compile the jade templates:

```
   jade: {
      html: {
        src: ['app/views/*.jade'],
        dest: 'app/views',
        options: {
          client: false
        }
      }
    },
```

I was able to integrate the `jade` task in **Yeoman's watch & reload tasks** by adding the following config in the `watch` task:

```
  watch: {
     ...
     jade: {
       files: 'app/views/*.jade',
       tasks: 'jade reload'
     },
     ...
  }
```

And all works wonderfully well... except that the initial compile does not occur unless I add the `jade` task to the command:

```
yeoman jade server
```

Our butler doesn't like this nice girl, because he won't let her integrate with his `server` task :) And that is annoying, since `yeoman server` will compile only coffeescript & compass files.

**Is there any way how I could add the `jade` task to the default execution of `yeoman server`?**

Comment: For the latest yeoman (1.0.0-x), there is an instruction on how to get this working: https://gist.github.com/kevva/5201657 Make sure you incorporate the changes as mentioned in the comments. I'm using 1.0.0-beta.4 and works for me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We created a guide on how to integrate Jade with Yeoman: [Using Yeoman and Jade](https://gist.github.com/passy/5229305)

Comment: I thought about that. Just hoped for a cleaner solution. But at the moment i'll do. Thanks

Comment: The 'original-server' task is running "clean" task, AFTER it has compiled our template - how do we solve this ?

Comment: If it's not enough to put the jade task in front or after the `original-server`, you can just replace the `server` task with `grunt.registerTask('server', 'clean jade task task task');` and make sure all the original tasks from /tasks/yeoman.js are included.

Comment: @SindreSorhus link is dead

Comment: @SindreSorhus it's dead

Answer (score 3):

make sure to add

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jade');
```

on top of your gruntfile, otherwise yeoman doesn't know how to handle the "jade" task

Comment: Of course... My grunt file works, only the yeoman integration did not. But @Sindre found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent guide to using Yeoman 1.0 and Jade together at https://gist.github.com/passy/5229305