# Yeoman template engine support

Tags: pug, template-engine, slim, yeoman

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating Jade in Yeoman’s server/watch/reload tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243245/integrating-jade-in-yeomans-server-watch-reload-tasks)

Coming from Rails, I'm wondering how to enable either jade or slim template support for Yeoman. It has been incredibly fast and satisfying to set up Yeoman, but I don't want to waste time coding HTML. Can someone point me in the right direction for getting jade or slim or something like that to work?

*Edit*

I found a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243245/integrating-jade-in-yeomans-server-watch-reload-tasks/14254041#14254041) here. Looks like yeoman doesn't support template languages out of the box.

Anyway, with this approach jade works just fine.